# The following fields are invalid stock moves stock lines

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

The below function will be called on a button click the objective is to create a picking and stock move for that picking that has been achieved while trying to save or when I click on any button it will show "The following fields are invalid: Stock Moves Move Lines"

```py
@api.multi
def request_done(self):
    values = {
                'picking_type_id' : self.picking_type_id.id,
                'location_id' : self.source_location_id.id,
                'location_dest_id' : self.dest_location_id.id,
                'move_type' : self.env['stock.picking']._defaults.get('move_type','direct'),
                'priority' : self.env['stock.picking']._defaults.get('priority','1'),
                'move_lines': ''
    }
    picking_obj = self.env['stock.picking'].create(values)
    move_ids = []
    for line in self.product_line_ids:
        vals = {
                'product_id' : line.product_id.id,
                'product_uom_qty' : line.approved_qty,
                'picking_id' : picking_obj.id,
                'product_uom' : line.product_id.uom_id.id,
                'location_id' : picking_obj.location_id.id,
                'location_dest_id' : picking_obj.location_dest_id.id,
                'name' : '',
                'reserved_quant_ids': False,
        }
        move = self.env['stock.move'].create(vals)
        move_ids.append(move.id)
    return{
            'name': 'Stock Quotation',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode':'form',
            'res_model': 'stock.picking',
            'type':'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_id': picking_obj.id,
            'nodeystroy': 'True',
            'context' : {'voucher': True, 'picking_id' : picking_obj.id}
        }
```

[image: Please check the image]

Comment: when the error appears. is ti when you reach the return statement or when you create the records

Comment: Code is working picking is created and moves, and the view is also returned, but when I edit or click on any button on the returned view will cause this error

Comment: because in stock picking XML view file these fields are required.